# Is there a good PaddlePaddle OCR example in Python?

Tags: ocr

I want to test PaddlePaddle OCR in Python and looking for some example code helping me to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it out in

https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR

or, a direct usage here,

https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.1/doc/doc_en/whl_en.md